# MSMTP using TLS/SSL

Tags: email, ssl, tls

I ty to send emails using MSMTP. I want to use TLS/SSL encryption for it.

Now I had to turn on the encryption in this lines:

```
 

# Enable or disable TLS/SSL encryption.

tls on

tls_starttls on

tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

My problem is from where I get the certificate to add it to /etc/ssl/.../ca-certificates.crt? I can download a letsencrypt .pem file from my hosting/email provider where I want to use the SMTP server to send the email. Do I have to add the .pem file in /etc/ssl/... and point to it in the MSMTP config file? Or do I have to generate one by myself or is a certificate still in /etc/ssl/... that I can use?

Comment: If you are lucky the Ubuntu package of such certs will be enough: `sudo apt-get install ca-certificates`